# run a function on several data sets using a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, lm

Say I have several datasets, `d1`,`d2`,`d3`, stored as a list:

```
a<-1:10
d1<-data.frame(a)
d2<-data.frame(a)
d3<-data.frame(a)
d1$b<-a*1
d2$b<-a*2
d3$b<-a*3

list<-c(d1,d2,d3)
```

I then have a function, that fits a regression.

```
fxn<- function(param1, param2, dataset){
    mod<-lm(dataset$param1~dataset$param2)
    return(coef(mod)[2])
}
```

I would like to feed this function the parameters to use for the regression (`a` and `b`) and then the list of data sets stored in `list`. Please note that this function doesn't work as I would like it to at the moment. I want it to calculate the dataset specific fits and return the slopes.

Comment: Try, lapply(list, fxn) .... don't use list as the name of your list.  It should be something like, A <- list(d1,d2,d3).  I don't know what you were trying to do with d1$b <- a*1 ???  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you would like the function to be like this then:

```
fxn<- function(param1, param2, dataset){
  #run model according to param1 and param2
  mod<-lm(dataset[,param1]~dataset[,param2])
  #calculate slope
  slope <- coef(mod)[2]
  #name it correctly
  names(slope) <- param2
  return(slope)
}
```

Then you could use an `lapply` to use the function for each data.frame:

```
lapply(list, function(x) fxn('a','b',x))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
b 
1 

[[2]]
  b 
0.5 

[[3]]
        b 
0.3333333
```

Data:

```
a<-1:10
d1<-data.frame(a)
d2<-data.frame(a)
d3<-data.frame(a)
d1$b<-a*1
d2$b<-a*2
d3$b<-a*3

#made a small change
#stored the data.frames in a list 
#as I assume you probably wanted
list<-list(d1,d2,d3)
```

Edit:

So, in order to create the format you mention in your comment you could do:

```
#first have the data.frames in a named list
list<-list(d1=d1,d2=d2,d3=d3)
```

and then do:

```
temp <- data.frame(t(data.frame(lapply(list, function(x) fxn('a','b',x)))))
#and if you want rownames as a column
temp$dfs <- row.names(temp)

> temp
           b dfs
d1 1.0000000  d1
d2 0.5000000  d2
d3 0.3333333  d3
```

Comment: this is close to perfect. Is there any way you can modify the output such that rather than printing what you have listed under "Output:" it prints a column of data set names (d1,d2,d3) ,and then a column of slopes (1, 0.5, 0.33333)?